# Why multi-thread get different output without sleep?

Tags: python, multithreading

I use `threading` to create 10 threads.

```
import threading
import time


def work():
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name} - work......")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work)
        t.start()
```

Here if I `sleep` for 1 second, I get different sorts of thread names each time.

The first time:

```
Thread-1 - work......
Thread-2 - work......
Thread-3 - work......
Thread-4 - work......
Thread-5 - work......
Thread-6 - work......
Thread-9 - work......
Thread-10 - work......
Thread-7 - work......
Thread-8 - work......

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The second time:

```
Thread-1 - work......
Thread-2 - work......
Thread-3 - work......
Thread-5 - work......
Thread-7 - work......
Thread-9 - work......
Thread-6 - work......
Thread-8 - work......
Thread-10 - work......
Thread-4 - work......

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I remove `time.sleep(1)`, I get the same output everytime.

```
Thread-1 - work......
Thread-2 - work......
Thread-3 - work......
Thread-4 - work......
Thread-5 - work......
Thread-6 - work......
Thread-7 - work......
Thread-8 - work......
Thread-9 - work......
Thread-10 - work......

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Anyone knows Why?

Comment: Threads don't start by themselves. The OS will schedule active threads to cores for execution. Putting a thread to sleep for 1s doesn't guarantee it will be scheduled for execution exactly 1 second later, to the nanosecond. It will be scheduled the next time the OS's scheduler checks whether there are active threads to schedule

Answer (score 0):

Mostly that's related to the amount of work that you're actually doing in each thread, and something called the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Python's multithreading isn't "true" multithreading because of the GIL. Only one task can actually execute at a time, and if your task is small enough then it won't live long enough to context-switch. However, in your `sleep` example, it's taking a long time (relatively speaking), which gives it the opportunity to swap context.

However, even if python *didn't* have the GIL, it's likely you'd still get the same deterministic output, because creating a thread has a certain overhead. If you have a fast enough function, the amount of time it takes to create a new thread will be longer than it takes the previous function to execute!

We can use some random expensive computation (recursion) to show this. Let's take this arbitrary work here:

```py
import threading

def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def calc_fib():
    n = 20
    res = fib(n)
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name} - {n}th fib: {res}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=calc_fib)
        t.start()
```

On my machine, the threads finish in the order they are created with n=20. It's still doing quite a bit of work, but each thread doesn't live long enough to context switch. Here is the output (though keep in mind, there could be some variability by machine):

```
➜  ~ python3 fib.py
Thread-1 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-2 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-3 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-4 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-5 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-6 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-7 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-8 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-9 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
Thread-10 (calc_fib) - 20th fib: 6765
```

But if we raise it to something like 30, it takes far too long for each function to terminate. In this case, we see a lot more randomization of the order in which the threads terminate:

```
➜  ~ python3 fib.py
Thread-7 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-8 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-3 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-4 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-2 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-5 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-1 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-6 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-10 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
Thread-9 (calc_fib) - 30th fib: 832040
```

In comparison, a language that doesn't use a GIL doesn't have the same effect. For instance, let's take this Rust example:

```rust
use std::thread::spawn;

fn fib(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n == 0 || n == 1 {
        return n;
    }

    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}

fn main() {
    let mut handlers = Vec::with_capacity(10);

    for i in 1..=10 {
        let t = spawn(move || {
            let n = 10;
            let res = fib(n);

            println!("Thread {} (calc_fib) - {}th fib: {}", i, n, res);
        });
        handlers.push(t)
    }

    for handler in handlers {
        handler.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

If we run this with n=10, here's what I get on my machine:

```
Thread 3 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 2 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 5 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 1 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 4 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 6 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 7 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 8 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 9 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
Thread 10 (calc_fib) - 10th fib: 55
```

Note, we can still sometimes get the same order of execution in Rust too:

[executing fibonacci sequence in Rust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10RVm.png)

edit: the screenshot is mostly in order, but I didn't even realize that threads 7, 8, and 9 actually got reordered in all of it